# Adding Spring controllers from different bundles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am importing / scanning `@RestController` classes from an external bundle through the OSGi framework.

So far, to enable handling of controllers from external bundles, I've had to write a custom `HandlerAdapter` which supports it:

```
private final Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> acceptedAnnotation = Set.of(Controller.class, RestController.class);

@Override
    public boolean supports(Object handler) {
        return handler.getClass().getClassLoader() instanceof BundleReference &&
            acceptedAnnotation.stream().anyMatch(a -> handler.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(a));
    }
```

A sample controller from a bundle looks like:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping()
    public Map<String, String> getWelcomeMessage() {
        return Map.of("all", "ok");
    }
}
```

If I omit the custom `HandlerAdapter`, then Spring doesn't have a `HandlerAdapter` to handle the controllers - I suspect the line below is required:

```
handler.getClass().getClassLoader() instanceof BundleReference
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.shamil.dxc.sample.controller.TestController cannot be cast to class org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod (net.shamil.dxc.sample.controller.TestController is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @6136998b; org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @402f32ff)
```

Is there a way I can get Spring to automatically map response types such that I don't need to have a custom `HandlerAdapter` and can use the `@RestController` and `@GetMapping` Request Mapping automatically?

Trying to use `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` internally brings exceptions `ClassCastException` as the Controller class is in a different bundle.